# Changing Button State OnClick

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, imagebutton

In Android, whenever I click a button (namely an ImageButton), I want to give the user feedback by changing the color of the button (maybe inverting colors, or darkening, etc). At this point, I don't want to change to a new button or anything, just want to change state so as to reflect the click.

I realize I can add a new drawable, so each button would have 2 states (when clicked, I would change to the second state).

That is (pseudocode):

> onClick {
>
> ```
>    ImageButton.setDrawable(R.drawable.myclickedbutton)
> ```
>
> }

Is there a better way to do this (I believe iOS will play with ImageColors for you when you click, and that's what I want here in Android), or is what I am thinking the only possibility?

I feel I'm missing something major with this concept.

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit**: If it makes a difference, my app runs on minimum target 2.2.

**Edit 2**: For clarification, I'm working with an *Image Button* which already has a custom drawable resource. That's what I want to manipulate onClick.

**Edit 3**: I don't think I'm being clear enough here. I know how to change the state using two drawables (whether it be onTouch, XML, onClick, etc.) I was asking if there was a way that Android (or some sort of method) can invert or darken colors for all buttons automatically when clicked (as iOS does, I believe). I am not asking how to do this on a button-to-button basis. This can be accomplished with 2 drawables per button, and I realize that.

Answer (score 2):

**button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
            <padding android:left="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip"
                android:right="10.0dip" android:bottom="10.0dip"/>
            <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="#222"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f1f1f1"/>
            <padding android:left="10.0dip" android:top="10.0dip"
                android:right="10.0dip" android:bottom="10.0dip"/>
            <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="#222"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Apply this button as background

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>
```

and in your class file do like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {

  pressedButton.setPressed(true);
}
```

so that the red color will be stable

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I want-- I don't want the button to have a single color (which is changed when clicked). It's an ImageButton which should be changed on click. It does already have a custom drawable source, the colors of which I would like to (invert, darken, etc.) on click to reflect the action.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use the code you mentioned in order to switch the drawables .
Rather create a drawable with two different states.

As you said you already have custom drawables, you can use them for different states.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/drawable1" /> <!-- for clicked state-->        
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable2" /> <!-- for normal state--> 
</selector>
```

place this xml as drawable_1.xml in drawable folder and use this drawable in your code,

```
yourButton.setDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_1)
```

Comment: I am aware of this method, just wondering if there's a workaround of using _2 drawables per button_. As of now, guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onTouchListener for button and change the state of button according to button click..

```
                button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                     {
                   // here u can change the button color or image as clickable as 
                   button.setBackgroundImage(R.drawable.image_pressed);

                     }
                     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                     {
                  // here u can change the button color or image as released as 
                   button.setBackgroundImage(R.drawable.image_released); 
                     }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

I think it may helpful to you..